# How to pass param from directive method to controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to send object from directive to controller `$scope` when method inoked but `file` printing undefined in controller , Any idea what is implemented wrong in below code ? 
main.html

```
<input type="file" file-model="myFile" callback-fn="uploadFile()"style="display: none;"/>
```

directive.js

```
angular.module('App').directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
         scope: { callbackFn: '&' },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                    console.log('test',element[0].files[0]);
                    var file = element[0].files[0];
                   scope.callbackFn(file);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

controller.js

```
    $scope.uploadFile = function(file){
       file = $scope.myFile;
           console.log('FILE',file);

        };
```

Comment: Does it matter that you are calling your `callback-fn` with no arguments? Try removing the "()" and see if it works then.

Comment: Nope! does not work without `()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send that parameter you should do a couple of changes:

Specify it in your expression:

```
<input type="file" file-model="myFile" callback-fn="uploadFile(file)"style="display: none;"/>
```

Then in your directive when calling that callback you must also specify it:

```
element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                console.log('test',element[0].files[0]);
                var file = element[0].files[0];
               scope.callbackFn({ file: file}); <--- here
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code snippet. `'='` sets up a two-way binding expression between the directive's isolated scope and the parent scope.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController)
  .directive('fileModel', fileModel);

DefaultController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function DefaultController($scope) {
  $scope.uploadFile = uploadFile;

  function uploadFile(file) {
    console.log('FILE', file);
  }
}

fileModel.$inject = ['$parse'];

function fileModel($parse) {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      callbackFn: '='
    },
    link: linkFunc
  };

  return directive;

  function linkFunc(scope, element, attrs) {
    var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
    var modelSetter = model.assign;

    element.bind('change', function() {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        var file = element[0].files[0];
        modelSetter(scope, file);
        console.log('test', file);
        scope.callbackFn(file);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController">
    <input type="file" file-model="myFile" callback-fn="uploadFile" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a service

```
app.service("fileHolder",fileHolder);
fileHolder.$inject = [];
function fileHolder(){
    var self = this,
    _file;
    self.setFile = setFile;
    self.getFile = getFile;

    function setFile(file){
        _file = file;
    }
    function getFile(){
        return _file;
    }
}
```

Then you can inject it into your directive and controller
And in the directive call:

```
fileHolder.setFile(element[0].files[0]);
```

And in the controller call getFile

```
 $scope.myFile = fileHolder.getFile();
```